# How do I Install IIS on Windows Server 2003 on AWS

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to install IIS on the Windows 2003 Datacenter x64 edition AMI on aws, however, it complains that it can't find the installation media "C:\WINDOWS\INSTALLATION\i386\amd64"?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm answering my own question, because I couldn't find an answer anywhere else.. the hint as in the path it was asking for "C:\WINDOWS\INSTALLATION\i386\amd64" .. if you look at the directory on the drive, it lists 2 folders under "C:\WINDOWS\INSTALLATION\": "i386" and "amd64".  The trick seems to be to change the path to the real folder.. in my case (installing 64bit), it was to make the path: "C:\WINDOWS\INSTALLATION\amd64".  Note, it may ask for this path 2-3 times.. but it worked.

Is this an issue with the AMI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, because I couldn't find an answer anywhere else.. the hint as in the path it was asking for "C:\WINDOWS\INSTALLATION\i386\amd64" .. if you look at the directory on the drive, it lists 2 folders under "C:\WINDOWS\INSTALLATION\": "i386" and "amd64".  The trick seems to be to change the path to the real folder.. in my case (installing 64bit), it was to make the path: "C:\WINDOWS\INSTALLATION\amd64".  Note, it may ask for this path 2-3 times.. but it worked.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been banging my head against a wall. I missed that it had the messed up path.  It was also helpful to know I needed to keep re-selecting the correct folder.